# Do I use % return, log return or diff of prices to plot ACF?

Tags: time-series, garch, log-returns, arima

I am reading a book on time series. To make a non-stationary series stationary, sometimes we need to difference the series. When it comes to finance, prices are non-stationary. Many authors fit ARMA models to return time series but returns are either log-return or % return which is different to simple differencing. I had a look at the ACF of % return and a simple diff and they are different.

My question is, is it valid to use percent or log return rather then diff to make a price series stationary?

Comment: When plotting the ACF you're investigating the temporal behaviour of the return-process, and then it is recommended to use log-returns, as opposed to % returns. In general, questioning whether to use arithmetic/% returns or log-returns have been addressed [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4160/discrete-returns-versus-log-returns-of-assets/7245#7245). Also, be aware that simply differencing the price process makes the differenced process non-comparable across asset dimension, which is one of the reasons we downscale the process with the previous price, as done with % returns.

Comment: With stocks diff of prices is not a good idea because when price is 10 a diff of 1 has very different meaning than when price is 50. (Stock prices change a lot over the long run). That is why people prefer to use % or log returns.

Comment: You can apply fractional differentiation to convert an input series to a stationary form: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58298/transforming-a-time-series/61390#61390